# Al recorrer array de objetos con for únicamente imprime el último elemento en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bucle-for

Tengo el siguiente código para recorrer el array de objetos e imprimir todos los elementos de dicho array, pero únicamente consigo que me imprima el último elemento.

```js
   function Disco(nombre, grupo, anho, tipo, localizacion){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.grupo = grupo;
        this.anho = anho;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.localizacion = localizacion;
        this.prestado = "false";
    }
    
    var disco1 = new Disco("Cosa", "Grupo", "1950", "rock", "0");
    var disco2 = new Disco("Coso", "Grupo2", "1952", "punk", "0");
    var disco3 = new Disco("Ceso", "Grupo3", "1954", "pop", "0");
    var disco4 = new Disco("Caso", "Grupo4", "1956", "rock", "0");
    var disco5 = new Disco("Case", "Grupo5", "1956", "rock", "0");
    
    var discos = new Array();
    
    discos.push(disco1,disco2,disco3,disco4,disco5);

    function mostrarDisco(){
        discos.forEach(function(disco){
            for(i=0; i<discos.length; i++)
            document.getElementById("discos").innerHTML = "<div>Título: <b>" + disco.nombre + "</b><br>"
            + "Grupo: <b>" + disco.grupo + "</b><br>" + "Año publicación: <b>" + disco.anho + "</b><br>"
            + "Género: <b>" + disco.tipo + "</b><br>" + "Estantería nº: <b>" + disco.localizacion + "</b><br>"
            + "Prestado: <b>" + disco.prestado + "</b><br></div>";
        });
}

mostrarDisco( )
```

```html
<div id="discos"></div>
```

El resultado que me da es:

> Título: Case
>   Grupo: Grupo5
>   Año publicación: 1956
>   Género: rock
>   Estantería nº: 0
>   Prestado: false

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas sobre escribiendo el html.  Te recomiendo que concatenes todo en una variable y modifiques el html una sola vez.  Tampoco necesitas el `for` anidado.  Quedaria asi:

```js
function Disco(nombre, grupo, anho, tipo, localizacion){
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.grupo = grupo;
        this.anho = anho;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.localizacion = localizacion;
        this.prestado = "false";
    }
    
    var disco1 = new Disco("Cosa", "Grupo", "1950", "rock", "0");
    var disco2 = new Disco("Coso", "Grupo2", "1952", "punk", "0");
    var disco3 = new Disco("Ceso", "Grupo3", "1954", "pop", "0");
    var disco4 = new Disco("Caso", "Grupo4", "1956", "rock", "0");
    var disco5 = new Disco("Case", "Grupo5", "1956", "rock", "0");
    
    var discos = new Array();
    
    discos.push(disco1,disco2,disco3,disco4,disco5);

    function mostrarDisco(){
        var html = "";
        discos.forEach(function(disco){            
            html += "<div>Título: <b>" + disco.nombre + "</b><br>"
            + "Grupo: <b>" + disco.grupo + "</b><br>" + "Año publicación: <b>" + disco.anho + "</b><br>"
            + "Género: <b>" + disco.tipo + "</b><br>" + "Estantería nº: <b>" + disco.localizacion + "</b><br>"
            + "Prestado: <b>" + disco.prestado + "</b><br></div>";
        });
        document.getElementById("discos").innerHTML = html;
}
mostrarDisco();
```

```html
<div id="discos"></div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @alanfcm